# Spring Service, Repository, Entity design pattern advice needed

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, entity

I've got a (hopefully) simple software design question: I want to make my entities (= domain objects which get persisted to DB) to be kinda immutable. Means: Entities should **only** get created by a service and every other part of the application works with an `interface` which only has getter methods.

**Example:**

1. `MyController` want to retrieve `MyEntity` with `id=5`
2. `MyController` has to ask `MyService` in order to get the object: `myService.getMyEntityById(5)`
3. `MyService` will ask the `MyEntityRepository` to fetch the Object from DB
4. `MyService` returns the `MyEntityInterface` to `MyController`

**Package design:**

```
root
  |--- service   
  |         |--- MyService.java
  |         |--- MyServiceImpl.java
  |         |
  |         |--- MyEntity.java
  |         |--- MyEntityImpl.java
  |         |
  |         |--- MyEntityRepository.java
  |
  |
  |------- web
            |--- MyController.java
```

**Ideas:**

My first idea was to simply use a package-protected constructor in `MyEntityImpl`, but this doesn't work some other libraries I'm using (i.e. Orika). So it must be `public`.

The next idea was to use the `MyEntity` interface. But now I've got some problem:

**Problems:**

The `MyService(Impl)` has a method called: `updateMyEntityData(MyEntity e, Data data)`. Now I can't be sure inside my service that this `MyEntity` object is really an instance of `MyEntityImpl`. Of course I could do an `if(e instanceof MyEntityImpl) ...` but that's exactly what I **don't** want to do.

The next problem is: This service method uses the `MyEntityRepository` which can save and retrieve `MyEntityImpl` objects, but can't handle the `MyEntity` interface. As a workaround I could do an additional DB query, but again that's **not** what I want:

```
void updateMyEntityData(MyEntity e, Data data) {
  MyEntityImpl impl = repo.findOne(e.getId());
  impl.setData(data);
  repo.saveToDB(impl);
}
```

This is an unnecessary DB query, because I **know** that `MyEntity` is an instance of `MyEntityImpl` and it's been created by this service, so it **must** be an object from DB. The other possibility is to use a cast:

```
void updateMyEntityData(MyEntity e, Data data) {
  MyEntityImpl impl = (MyEntityImpl) e;
  impl.setData(data);
  repo.saveToDB(impl);
}
```

**Summary:**

- Only the service is allowed to construct `MyEntityImpl`
- `MyService(Impl)` must be able to modify fields of `MyEntityImpl` afterwards (means: there must be setters)
- Avoid unnecessary DB queries

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Package protected setters? You could also use composition rather than inheritance - return a class that wraps `MyEntityImpl` and `implements MyEntity`. It should provide a package-private `getMyEnitityImpl` method that the DAO can use to persist. If you use [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) then [@Delegate](http://projectlombok.org/features/Delegate.html) can do this in 3 lines of code...

Comment: You're overthinking this one and introducing complexity for little or no benefit - the various benefits of immutability come once the object is constructed, where that construction happens is of little importance in respect to this.  Forcing your service to be used to construct domain objects increases the coupling in your application because you'll end up passing the service about rather than the just depending on the domain class.  Like-wise splitting your domain classes between interface and impl just adds to the complexity of the code base and is, imho, unnecessary.

Comment: Hmm... My initial thought was: *Without it, some Controller or some other service could create an instance of `MyEntity` and call `myService.updateMyEntityData(...)`*. Then I cannot be sure if the object passed is really an object from DB or if it was created somewhere else.

Comment: Just leave away the interface MyEntity. Just work with it directly. What would a compatible entity look like and would you like to store it to the same db tables?

Comment: The Entity is nothing special. As stated above, I want just to be sure that the service can only be called with objects which come from DB. The interface will only get implemented **once**. It's just about making the Entity immutable after it leaves the Service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to get over the public constructor.  Given only objects retrieved from the repository/DB can have a valid *identity* assigned, you can use this to control updates.

Yes, you could guess identities, but you could do a whole load of daft things to work round whatever protection you think you're putting in place - utlimately, I can create an instance and assign the fields with relfection if I choose.

Now, immutability is a more noble goal, at least in a multithreaded environment (if you're not in a environment where multiple threads perform updates then the benefits are less obvious and, imho, not worth the cost).

The problem is immutablity conflicts with domain entities that are typically be mutated.  A common approach to this problem is to include a timestamp indicating when the last mutation was committed and to use mutated copy.  Here's an example of a clean way to create a mutated copy using the *builder* pattern:

```
public MyEntity
{
  private Object identity;
  private long mutated;
  private Data data;

  public MyEntity(Object identity, long mutated, Data data)
  {
    this.identity = identity;
    this.mutated= mutated;
    this.data = data;        
  }

  public Object getIdentity()
  {
    return this.identity;
  }

  public Data getData()
  {
    return this.data;
  }

  public Builder copy()
  {
    return new Builder();
  }

  public class Builder
  {
    private Data data = MyEntity.this.data;

    public Builder setData(Data data)
    {
      this.data = data;  
    }

    public MyEntity build()
    {
      return new MyEntity(MyEntity.this.identity, MyEntity.this.mutated, this.data);
    }
  }
}
```

The calling code would look like this:

```
MyEntity mutatedMyEntity = myEntity.copy().setData(new Data()).build();
```

While this approach keeps things relatively clean, it introduces the problem of multiple threads creating mulitple mutated copies at the same time.

Depending on you exact requirements, this means you'll need to detect conflicts when the changes are committed (your `saveToDB` method) by checking that the mutated timestamp with the latest version (to avoid two database hits, it's best to do the lot in a stored procedure, though alternatives would be to keep a cache of identities to mutated timestamps in the class performing the writes).  The conflict resolution will again be down to your specific requirements as will propogating changes to the other instances of the same entity.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using MongoDB, so every Object in DB will have an UUID. Here's a real-world problem from my Application where immutability would be nice: User passwords can only be set using a passwordRecoveryKey, and thus only the UserService has access to the User and PasswordRecoveryKey from DB. Now, if the User is mutable, it's possible to call `u.setPassword(newPassword); userService.updateUser(User u, DataToUpdate d);` (the `updateUser` method just updates the fields in `u` and then saves the whole obj to DB). In this the scenario the password can get updated from everywhere without token

Comment: Isn't solved by the `Builder` if it only has a `setPassword` method and the same apply in avoiding conflicts so that the password recovery key isn't used multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

I've now used a more simple approach:

```
public class MyEntity {

  MyEntity() {

  }

  @Id
  private ObjectId id;
  public ObjectId getId() { return id; }

  private String someOtherField;
  public String getSomeOtherField() { return someOtherField; }
  setSomeOtherField(String someOtherField) { this.someOtherField = someOtherField; }

}
```

If the Entity has some "final" fields, it get's a second constructor, because Spring Data throws an exception if it can't map the field names to the constructor parameter names, and this way always works:

```
public class MyEntity {

  protected MyEntity() {} // this one is for Spring Data,
                          // because it can't map
  MyEntity(Integer i) {   // this constructor param "i"
    this.finalInt = i;    // to a field named "i". (The
  }                       // field is called "finalInt")

  @Id
  private ObjectId id;
  public ObjectId getId() { return id; }

  private Integer finalInt;
  public Integer getFinalInt() { return finalInt; }

  private String someOtherField;
  public String getSomeOtherField() { return someOtherField; }
  setSomeOtherField(String someOtherField) { this.someOtherField = someOtherField; }

}
```

Package layout is like this:

```
root
  |--- service   
  |         |--- MyService.java (public interface)
  |         |--- MyServiceImpl.java (package protected class implements MyService)
  |         |
  |         |--- MyEntity.java (public class)
  |         |
  |         |--- MyEntityRepository.java (package protected)
  |
  |
  |------- web
            |--- MyController.java
```

Now the `Controller` can't construct own `Entity` objects (at least not while using the constuctor) and it has to use the `Service` (which get's wired by Spring to `ServiceImpl`).

The `Repository` can't be accessed by the `Controller` because it's package protected, and thus can only be used by the `Service`.

It's also only possible for the `Service` (and `Repository`) to modify the contents of an `Entity` because all setters are package protected.

I think this is a pretty nice solution, which can prevent a lot of bad code like

- Repository access inside the Controller code
- Entity modification in Controller and saving to DB without the `Service` having control over that
- Passing invalid (self-constructed) objects through the application, which have for example no ID.

Of course it's still possible to use reflection to bypass it, BUT that's not the point. The whole thing is not about *security*, it's about *clean code* and a *well structured application* where the *data and control flow is clearly defined*.